# Spring boot @Scheduled task goes into oblivion with no trace after a while

Tags: spring-boot

I have several tasks @Scheduled with fixedDelay. Thread pool size in application.properties is sufficiently larger than the number of these tasks. One of the tasks routinely stops doing anything as seen from the lack of activity in the log files from that task. There is no uncaught exception and even if there were ,the next invocation of the schedule should not be affected. The task does IO operations (network calls). What could possibly cause this?

Comment: Swallowed exception perhaps or even probably, though I'm guessing. I suggest narrowing down the problem area by looking at the last entry in the logs. The problem should be in the area between the last reported log entry and the expected next log entry.

Comment: Even a swallowed exception can't affect the next (fixedDelay=60000) invocation from happening (and that will write some logs) right?